# Regex for parsing functions in a file getting lost

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, grammar

I making a application for search and store functions names for xHabour language.

For getting all function in a single archive I parse all the content using

```cs
  RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
  string[] parts = Regex.Split(content, @"(static|^^).*function\s(.*)\)", options);
```

The `content` variable contains all buffer from the file I parsing

I the most cases he get all the function OK, but in the middle of some function the word `FUNCTION` appears and the regex is getting too

A example of code:

```
Function dropProcedure(cProcedure, cDatabase )

local cCmdSql := ''

cProcedure := lower( cProcedure )

cCmdSql := 'DROP FUNCTION if exists '+cDataBase+'.`'+cProcedure+'`'+CRLF 

return sqlexecute( cCmdSql )
```

My question is how I can avoid that cases using the regex

off: I trying to use the [language grammar](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars) TextMate schema but I not find any example in C# to use this schema parser or how vscode ([here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars)) implements the parser from then (I found the entire schema for xharbour/harbour [here](https://github.com/APerricone/harbourCodeExtension/blob/master/client/syntaxes/harbour.tmLanguage.json))

Comment: Does `(static|^).*?function\s(.*)\)` work for you?

Comment: No, he is getting the function inside the "string" declaration

Comment: This is why regex is not suitable to parse programming languages, its for processing simple regular expressions

Comment: @TheGeneral yes, but is working in this case, the only case I missing is that function inside the string

Comment: If you want to go down this route, it would be optimal to show the types of function signatures you need to parse, so someone can compose a more appropriate regex

Comment: The functions are declared that way, the grammar scheme is on the description too. But all the function is ```[?static] function [name]([...params])```

Comment: @TheGeneral and a really searching for a example to implement the TextMate schema for create this application, but is hard to found the information about that

Comment: Could you get rid of `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` and change `function` to `[Ff]unction`?

Comment: @jdaz I tried that too, but the language accept upper case in "function" words. I believe I will need to use some lexical search for parse the language and get the data from the source files.

Comment: I found a library for tokenize the language using the tmLanguage archive from TextMate grammar (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-textmate)

Answer (score 0):

I was going to point you to the link you already had up. In harbour functions are at the start of a line, or at least  after a `;` I'd use that to my advantage

```
(?:^|;)\s*(?:static\s)?\s*function\s+(\w+)
```

`(:?` is the start of a non-capture group I'm saying it now and leaving it out for the rest of my explaination

`^|;` Look for the start of a line or a ; which breaks a line in harbour

`\s*` look for any amount of whitespace (`\n` `\r` `\t`  )

`(:?static\s)?` optionally look for the word static followed by a whitespace

`\s*` any whitespace again

`function` look for the word function. You may want `(?:function|procedure|method)` instead, and this isn't quite full, only the first 4 letters of a key word are needed, the rest are all optional, but that gets ugly, you can see that in the github link you posted.

`\s+` some amount of whitespace

`(\w+)` capture the function name. This will stop at a ( or a space, but gets alphanumeric and underscores.

Hopefully this isn't too late to help.